# In Authorize.Net, What is the difference between sandbox.authorize.net and test.authorize.net?

Tags: authorize.net

I have crawled thru the site, and i cant see any difference between the two.
I don't know when should i use the sandbox and test.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're exactly the same thing.

Comment: out of curiosity, I consider this tag wiki to be plagiarized text, don't you? http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/753591?&_suid=1349358891593006506837999562215 --> https://github.com/ztellman/lamina